# Rendering .Net controls through Handler for Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, handler

I have an `ASP.Net` application that has a `UserControl` that needs to be rendered on an `ASPX` page (as normal), but also via `Ajax` using a Handler.

One solution to this is to get the `UserControl` to simply build up a `HTML` `string`, rather than rendering controls as it would normally.

That way, the `ASPX` page can simply populate a `Literal` control with the output, while the Handler can write the output to the Response object for `Ajax` to pick up.

Is this the ideal solution? are there any drawbacks of this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do that, you have to recreate the user control every time from the client-side when a postback to the server happens.  However, performance wise, that may be better.  However, I don't think the UC can then participate with viewstate and the ASP.NET object model as a typical user control would.  You would have to account that all actions within the UC are handled appropriately, to react to the web.

If you have a large amount of content to render, the UC approach is just fine.  We're talking rendering markup and injecting it into the UI, and so that does pan out and can make it easier.  If it's not that much markup, any alternative would do.

If all you need to do is push data to the client, an alternative could be that you push JSON to the client through a web service, and build the UI on the client.  That's efficient too.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks - my thoughts too.  Looking at a JSON option for the Ajax part, though it probably won't offer a huge difference in download size, because most of the HTML is database-drawn anyway.

Comment: In that case,I agree, direct JSON transfer isn't going to be a huge savings.  But it still may be a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of JS templating tools available now that will solve this problem.  Take a look at mustache js, which can allow the same template to be rendered in client side JS and in C#.Net.

You can then create on template file and either render the HTML in JS via Ajax or render in .Net and simply output during page load.